# converting an NSString with accented characters to a CString

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring

I have an NSString with a value of Jose (an accent on the e). I try to convert it to a C string as follows:

```
char str [[myAccentStr length] + 1];
[myAccentStr getCString:str maxLength:[myAccentStr length] + 1 encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
```

but str ends up being an empty string. What gives? I tried UTF8 and UTF16 too. It gets passed to another function later on and when that funcsion calls lstrlen on it, the size comes out as zero.

Comment: While searching in apple dev forums, I found something telling me to try using the NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding. I tried that and that is closer but not quite there yet - I get the string minus the accented characters(e.g. Jos instead of Jose).

Comment: Have you tried using `[str UTF8String]`? That's the most common way people convert an NSString* to a CString.

Comment: I didn't try that, but turns out I have other issues. The answer below got me past the first hurdle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJGIEIE) says:

> You can use canBeConvertedToEncoding: to check whether a string can be
>   losslessly converted to encoding. If it can’t, you can use
>   dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: to get a C-string
>   representation using encoding, allowing some loss of information (note
>   that the data returned by dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion: is
>   not a strict C-string since it does not have a NULL terminator).

Using the NSString method [dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-dataUsingEncoding_) does the trick.  Here's a code example:

```
NSString *myAccentStr = @"José";
char str[[myAccentStr length] + 1];

// NSString * to C String (char*)
NSData *strData = [myAccentStr dataUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding 
                                allowLossyConversion:YES];
memcpy(str, [strData bytes], [strData length] + 1);
str[[myAccentStr length]] = '\0';
NSLog(@"str (from NSString* to c string): %s", str);

// C String (char*) to NSString *   
NSString *newAccentStr = [NSString stringWithCString:str 
                                            encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"newAccentStr (from c string to NSString*):  %@", newAccentStr);
```

The output from that NSLog is:

> str (from NSString* to c string): José
>
> newAccentStr (from c string to NSString*):  José

So far I've only seen this work properly when using the NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding.

---

### Edit

Changing this to a community wiki.  Please feel free to edit.

hooleyhoop had some great points, so I thought I would try to make code that is as verbose as possible.  If I'm missing anything, someone please chime in.

Also - Not sure why [NSString canBeConvertedToEncoding:] is returning YES even though the [NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:] function definitely isn't working right (as seen by the output).

Here's some code to help in analyzing what works / what doesn't:

```
// Define Block variable to tests out different encodings
void (^tryGetCStringUsingEncoding)(NSString*, NSStringEncoding) = ^(NSString* originalNSString, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    NSLog(@"Trying to convert \"%@\" using encoding: 0x%X", originalNSString, encoding);
    BOOL canEncode = [originalNSString canBeConvertedToEncoding:encoding];
    if (!canEncode)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Can not encode \"%@\" using encoding %X", originalNSString, encoding);
    }
    else
    {
        // Try encoding using NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:
        NSUInteger cStrLength = [originalNSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:encoding];
        char cstr[cStrLength];
        [originalNSString getCString:cstr maxLength:cStrLength encoding:encoding];
        NSLog(@"    Converted(1): \"%s\"  (expected length: %u)",
              cstr, cStrLength);

        // Try encoding using NSString dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:          
        NSData *strData = [originalNSString dataUsingEncoding:encoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        char cstr2[[strData length] + 1];
        memcpy(cstr2, [strData bytes], [strData length] + 1);
        cstr2[[strData length]] = '\0';
        NSLog(@"    Converted(2): \"%s\"  (expected length: %u)",
              cstr2, [strData length]);
    }
};

NSString *myAccentStr = @"José";

// Try out whatever encoding you want
tryGetCStringUsingEncoding(myAccentStr, NSUTF8StringEncoding);
tryGetCStringUsingEncoding(myAccentStr, NSUTF16StringEncoding);
tryGetCStringUsingEncoding(myAccentStr, NSUTF32StringEncoding);
tryGetCStringUsingEncoding(myAccentStr, NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding);
```

Results:

```
> Trying to convert "José" using encoding: 0x4
>     Converted(1): ""  (expected length: 5)
>     Converted(2): "Jos√©"  (expected length: 5)
> Trying to convert "José" using encoding: 0xA
>     Converted(1): ""  (expected length: 8)
>     Converted(2): "ˇ˛J"  (expected length: 10)
> Trying to convert "José" using encoding: 0x8C000100
>     Converted(1): ""  (expected length: 16)
>     Converted(2): "ˇ˛"  (expected length: 20)
> Trying to convert "José" using encoding: 0x1E
>     Converted(1): "-"  (expected length: 4)
>     Converted(2): "José"  (expected length: 4)
```

Comment: I tried it and it works pretty well! If I may ask, how about the other way, cstring to NSString? My brain I think has shutdown... :(

Comment: I updated the code example to include how to go the other way (c string to NSString*)

Answer (score 1):

`[aString length]` returns the number of characters. In your case this is **4**.

You can convert your string to a c string accurately using, for example, *NSUTF8StringEncoding*, *NSUTF16StringEncoding*, *NSUTF32StringEncoding*. The length *in bytes* would be **5**, **8**, **16** respectively.

```
NSString *myAccentStr = @"José";
NSUInteger l1 = [myAccentStr lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger l2 = [myAccentStr lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSUInteger l3 = [myAccentStr lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld", (long)l1, (long)l2, (long)l3);

> 5, 8, 16
```

For conversion purposes you should use `-maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding` instead of `-lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding`

Always check that the conversion is valid with `-canBeConvertedToEncoding`

There are good reasons to use NSString

Comment: I would not voluntarily stray away from NSString, trust me, but this is something I have to pass in to a third-party library.

Comment: @Ahmad - what result are you hoping for? Would you want 'José' to become 'Jose' or do you want to preserve the original? What would you expect to happen to a name such as '中国, 中华' or ☃ ?

Comment: @hooleyhoop +1 I like your answer.  I wish I knew more of the "why" as to why -[NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:] doesn't work properly.  Admittedly I think I was originally using the wrong lengths because I didn't use the -[NSString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:] method that you propose in your answer.  Still... not coming out right (at least for me) until I use -[NSString dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:].  Perhaps it's the allowLossyConversion part of that last function that allows it to succeed.  Still...  It has the accented e and everything.

Comment: @sam - your [NSString getCString:maxLength:encoding:] is working perfectly. It is your NSLog that isn't :)

Comment: @hooleyhoop What's the best way to view the cstring to verify whether it is correct or not?  I tried printf and it does vary from nslog but not sure I am viewing the c string correctly. Jose still wasn't showing up right until the [NSString dataUsingEncoding...] call when viewing using printf.

Comment: @sam - the best way to log a cstring that isn't MacRoman to the console is to convert it to an NSString with the correct encoding :)

Comment: @sam - the bigger picture here is if you have an arbitrary NSString that you must pass to a library as a cstring you must know which encodings the library supports. If the library supports more than one encoding it must let you specify the encoding you are using. Ok it could guess, but there will be cases where it is incorrect.

Comment: @hoolehyhoop - I was hoping for Jose (with the accent on the e, not sure how to do that on this keyboard I'm on at the moment). I don't need to support asian languages at the moment.